# get the highest and lowest number in an array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi i have a service desk application, i have a dropdown which populates list of categories and on user picking the value it automatically binds another dropdown showing list of admin agents assigned to each of these categories.

Now the problem is if more than 1 admin agent is assigned to a partiular category, i want to be able to count the total number of open tickets before each agents and get the lowest of all and bind the one with the lowest number of tickets to the dropdown text. so there wont be need of a user picking an admin agent to assign the work to.
Heres my code.pls help.

```
 ------------------category dropdown that binds assigness dropdown-----------
  Protected Sub ddlcategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim TK As GHD5.TicketCategory = (New cls_ticketcategories).SelectThisID(ddlcategory.SelectedValue)
        mod_filldropdowns.FillAssignees(ddlassignee, TK.CategoryID)
        If ddlassignee.Items.Count = 0 Then
            Msgbox1.ShowHelp("No Agent for " & ddlcategory.SelectedValue & "")
            'ElseIf ddlassignee.Items.Count > 1 Then
            '    For Each rec As GHD5.User In ddlassignee.Items
            '       select * from tickets where status is 'open' and assigne = list of assigness
                    count()
                   get lowest number in each record retun
bind dropdown with assignee username

            '    Next
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End Sub


-------code to fill assigness dropdown based on category ID selected-----------------

   Public Sub FillAssignees(ByVal cb As ASPxComboBox, ByVal categoryid As Integer)
        Dim obj As List(Of GHD5.User) = (New cls_users).SelectuserbycategoryID(categoryid)

        cb.DataSource = obj
        cb.Columns.Clear()
        cb.Columns.Add("UserID").Width = 50
        cb.Columns.Add("Username").Width = 100
        cb.Columns.Add("firstname").Width = 100
        cb.Columns.Add("Lastname").Width = 150
        cb.ValueField = "Username"
        cb.TextField = "UserID"
        cb.TextFormatString = "{0},{1}"
        cb.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Min()` and `Max()` for arrays and Lists.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 15, 7, 9 };

int min = array.Min();
int max = array.Max();


List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 15, 7, 9 };

int min = list.Max();
int max = list.Max();
```

Comment: So please how do i use it in between these block of codes to fix this.